# Linq multi keyword search

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, search

I have a situation where i have Keyword column in table which contains comma separated keywords. User can provide multiple search terms to search against the Keyword column. For example user provides the below search terms "one,two,three" and the db column may contain any of the "one" ,"two", "three" or none of them. how can I write a query which matches against any of the provided search term.

I have tried the below

```
string[] searchTerm = {"one","two","three"};

query =Product.Where( p=> searchTerm.Any(val => p.Keywords.Contains(val)));
```

and

```
var query=db.Products;

 foreach (string searchword in searchTerm)
  {
    query = query.Where(c => c.Keywords.Contains(searchword ));
  }
```

but its not working for me.
Thanks,

Comment: Well, your database is incorrectly designed. You should never have a column that contains a list, in whatever format. You should create a new table that holds the keywords and that has a foreign key to the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the text provided by the user in different keywords, as in converting "one,two",three" in a string[], you could do something like:

```
 string [] keys = keywords.Split(',');
 var query = new List<Product>();
 foreach (var item in keys)
 {
    query = query.Concat ((IEnumerable<Product>)Product.Where(x=>x.KeyWords.Contains(item))).ToList();
 }
```

Example:

```
List<Product> ass = new List<Product>();

Product a = new Product();
a.KeyWords = "one, two, three";

Product a1 = new Product();
a1.KeyWords = "one, three";

Product a2 = new Product();
a2.KeyWords = "five";

ass.Add(a);
ass.Add(a1);
ass.Add(a2);

string userInput = "one, seven";

string [] keys = userInput.Split(',');
var query = new List<Product>();
foreach (var item in keys)
{
    query = query.Concat ((IEnumerable<Product>)ass.Where(x=>x.KeyWords.Contains(item))).ToList();
}

foreach (var item in query )
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.KeyWords);
}
```

Prints:

```
one, two, three
one, three
```

Comment: Thanks lcarus...it is helpful but still for me its ANDing the query it should be ORing...so it works if user inputs one,two,three but fails if user inputs one,nine,eleven

Comment: @user784552 The example I provided is an OR, not an AND. You need to split the keywords entered by the **USER** (you said it's comma-separated) and go in the foreach loop through all of them concatenating the ones that match. For example, if your table column has "one,two,twenty three" and the user enters "one, five" it will match because both, column in the table and user input contain "one".